# Does Config DB deactivate Automation scripts in Maximo?

Tags: automation, maximo

In Maximo, while performing config DB, does the system deactivate Automation Scripts as well (apart from stopping Cron tasks, killing user sessions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, object and attribute launch points are disabled during admin mode.

Answer (score 1):

To be a little more accurate, "Admin Mode" is what disables the Automation Script launch points, whether or not Maximo ever runs a configdb. That's because it disables the whole "event" system in Maximo (which Automation Scripts leverage), so other internal logic that uses this system (that were around long before Automation Scripts and Admin Mode were) also does not run. The most insidious one of those for me has been the business logic that fills in the ancestor tables (any of them).

> **"Admin Mode" function in Maximo 7.x**
>
> 3) It disables all event listeners.
>   When the Maximo application server starts (when services are loaded), all event listeners will be loaded . For example: PMListener, MatUseTransListener , AssetListener etc.
>   If "Admin Mode" is "ON", all event listeners are disabled even if they are initialized when the Maximo application server starts.
>   At that time, if you try to do some business processes such as Asset creation, PM creation or issue/return Inventory items, data integrity would be broken.
>   For example: inventory balances/cost are not updated or asset data is not inserted in ASSETANCESTOR, etc.
>   Also, due to broken data integrity , some unexpected errors or results will happen, for example: PM Wogen error.

From: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377175